# Xcode is not able to recognize smart svn changes

Tags: ios, smartsvn

Actually i checkout project from svn using smartsvn,after that i modified some files but if i take update from some other system files are getting copied but they are not adding in build settings.How can i get build settings using svn

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are committing your code before taking checkout of your code in another system. For detailed information , read the official docs of smart svn:

http://www.smartsvn.com/doc/display/SU